# how to merge rows in google dataprep

Tags: arrays, json, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataprep

I am really struggling with google data prep as there is no much information about this.

lets say i have data:

```
{"name":"john","age":21,"dob":"1988-01-01","tags":["a","b"],"address":{"postcode":3122,"state":"vic"},"lineItems":[{"itemID":"item001","unitPrice":1000},{"itemID":"item002","unitPrice":2000}]}
{"name":"aom","age":21,"dob":"1988-02-01","tags":["c","d"],"address":{"postcode":3000,"state":"Vic"},"lineItems":[{"itemID":"item003","unitPrice":3000},{"itemID":"item004","unitPrice":4000}]}
```

then my next step was to flatten the array into rows in order to clean the data. In this case, it will create 4 rows in total.

Now, I don't know how to merge rows based on name for example.

The function of merge is only to merge columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A (workaround) solution that I was able to come up with is to introduce a constant column using "derive" and then to pivot.

[image: Pivot details]

Comment: Hi Lars, Thanks for the answers. Yes, that is the workaround. Unfortunately, when the result is exported to bigquery. The array is recognised as a 'STRING'. I have asked to Trifacta, apparently, it seems this is their limitation.